# I want to fetch specific data from a table using zend model class using this->select

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

> ```
> public function getDataByMenuId($menu_id)
>   {
>       $select = $this->select()->where('menu_id=?', $menu_id);
>       $result = $this->fetchAll($select);
>       if ($result) {
>           return $result->toArray();
>       } else {
>           return NULL;
>       }
>   }
> ```

the above code fetching all the data from the table but i want only some data in the table 
Edit: I mean to say I want fetch some columns of every row any thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Only some? Some? Really? :)
If "SOME" = 4
then You can use:

```
$select = $this->select()->where('menu_id=?', $menu_id)->limit(4);
```

You can try also:

```
$select = $this->select()->where('menu_id=?', $menu_id)->limit(SOME);
```

If You have defined Your some constant ;)